# Display raster outlines

Tags: qgis, raster, arcgis-10.1, symbology

I guess mine is a very simple task, however I don't know how to solve it.
I m trying to display the outlines of a raster created from a polygon shp.
What I would like to come up with is an image where I can visualize the outlines of each poligon within my raster image. This image has two different colours (namely two "classes") and one is switched off, so only one is visible. Here is an example of what I need (but this is a shp, my image now only displays the yellow parts, while I also need the black lines):
[image]

I work both with ArGIS 10.1 and QGIS 1.8. Any idea?

Comment: do you only want the outlines of the yellow areas? Perhaps i have read the question wrong. Maybe when you have the polygons in shp covert to lines then to raster. Have not tried it but presume it would work. Possibly totally off the mark here.

Comment: I tried it, but it creates a raster with many colours and only for the outlines, with no colours filling the polygons. What I need is something like a polygon to raster function which would preserve the outlines of the shapefile as well.

Comment: is not a simple export as TIFF sufficient for you? Menue File > [Export](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exporting_your_map/00sm00000004000000/)

Comment: I'm unclear what your specific problem is.  Are you having issues with displaying the product of polyline to raster?  Do you need to reclassify your raster dataset so there is only one value for each pixel value?